# Is it possible to create a shortcut for creating constant from a string bypassing the refactoring menu?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

i'm quite new in intelliJ. I'm a way more proficient with eclipse IDE and its shortcuts. I updated the keymap of intelliJ to use the eclipse shortcuts.

Now, i need to extract string in classes and use them as constants who the hell i can do it with breaking the custom eclipse keymap provided in intelliJ.

The eclipse's "shortcut" was the <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. But as you guess unuseful in Intellij.

Thanks a lot people in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select part of the code you want to add to a **variable** and press:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

or

> <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>

if you are on MacOS

Comment: Thanks, tough. I was searching for ctrl + alt + c. your answer guided me.